# How should the Joel Test be updated for 2010?

Tags: configuration-management

I believe [the Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) was written in 2000. It is time for an update to more align with modern times. I'll start:

1. Do you use source control?

changed to

1. Do you have quality gates in place for each check-in?

Many of the Joel Test assumptions are no longer true. I don't think we need to ask today if an organization uses source control, contains a bug database, or has a "spec". On the other hand, some of the Joel test items are as relevant as ever: up-to-date schedule and state-of-the-art tools.

Help me update the list for 2010 so I can take it to management once again.

Comment: Might be worth making this community wiki

Comment: 'I don't think we need to ask today if an organization uses source control, contains a bug database, or has a "spec"' . . . honestly, I wouldn't be so sure

Comment: I agree with Binary Worrier - things don't change *that* much. Look at "The Mythical Man MOnth" - written in 1975, and much of it still holds true today over 30 years later!

Comment: Agreed, my organisation doesn't use a bug database... admiteddly that's because it's a pretty new start-up and we haven't gotten around to setting anything up yet. It's not a valid assumption though.

Comment: I think the Joel Test is very simple assessment of company. There are many company models and approaches that depend on company size, goals, business plans and so on which you could discuss forever. If you have small highly experienced team working on inhouse software with one developer per ~5 applications where each developer maintains his own set of applications then most of the items on the list will miss the point. I believe the list is good for the average company - but highly experienced developers don't work in those :)

Comment: Eh... I voted for "subj/arg". It's a poll / discussion question, and seems geared more toward refreshing the buzzwords than actually coming up with anything new and interesting. Check out the links at right under the "Related" heading for other Joel Test questions...

Comment: 1.Do you have a change management system?
2.Can everyone make a build in one step?
3.Do your daily build include automated tests?
4.Is work item tracking integrated with source control?
5.Do you fix bugs and write new code?
6.Do you track progress and manage change?
7.Do you have a requirements management system?
8.Do programmers have quiet working conditions and teaming rooms?
9.Do you use the best tools money can buy?
10.Are your testers involved in requirements management?
11.Do new candidates review code during their interview?
12.Do you do hallway usability testing?

Comment: Better than the cartoon questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Will the organization exist in 6 months time?

Comment: 1.Do you have a change management system? 2.Can everyone make a build in one step? 3.Do your daily build include automated tests? 4.Is work item tracking integrated with source control? 5.Do you fix bugs and write new code? 6.Do you track progress and manage change? 7.Do you have a requirements management system? 8.Do programmers have quiet working conditions and teaming rooms? 9.Do you use the best tools money can buy? 10.Are your testers involved in requirements management? 11.Do new candidates review code during their interview? 12.Will the organization exist in 6 months time?

I like it.